# How can I create a connection/link between Excel and an Outlook email?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I've been sending Outlook emails from Excel for a while, using it to manage my sales and project management activities at work. I've been enjoying increased productivity from it, so I want to do some more advanced things. For example, I think I have the code worked out, probably in a crude way, to have Excel help keep track of emails that have not been replied to. (I simply have Outlook, for each new email, open a workbook, and create a record in a new row, then have Excel attempt to match it to an email I previously sent.)

But once I have a record in Excel of such an email, it has no link or connection to the actual email. I want to be able to click on the Excel icon or link for the email, and then pull up the actual email.

I have found possibilities in using EntryIDs and MessageIDs, Outlook URLs and GUIDs,and even good-old AdvancedSearch (but I think having Excel search for an email that it initiated seems pretty clunky; there should be a way to create a hard link to the email).

Relatedly, and also probably just as clunky, but I've pondered "embedding" a unique identifier in each Excel-initiated email, that could be used to find it and link it back to a record in Excel. In an HTML email, I can add a string of numbers under my signature, in white text on a white background, and it's not perfect but in most cases should go unnoticed, and would allow my spreadsheet to positively identify it (as a reply to a particular email, etc.)

I know we're not supposed to ask for "advice" but I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to something that may work for what I hope to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the email's time sent (TIMESTAMP - MMDDYYYYHHSS), Recipient, and Subject Line as unique, identifying markers? Add these fields to your row data. Then, after email is sent, create a macro event that will:

1. Launch the Outlook App
2. Open the Sent Folder
3. Loop through all items
4. Filter email to the markers (Time, Recipient, Subject Line) of the active Excel row
5. Open the Email Item

---

Aside, my personal advice is to use a database like MS Access which works great with its siblings, Excel and Outlook. Also, it is designed to maintain relationships between data elements. Access could hold all the needed email content (emailID, recipient, subject, body, date, emailsent?) and with forms can provide AfterUpdate, ButtonClick, OnOpen events to manage the process of data entry, email process, data update, so on. If only you knew the increased productivity that comes with a relational database!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user property to the MailItem class. See the [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862196.aspx) collection for more information.

The automated systems add an ID to the end if the [Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865652(v=office.15).aspx) line.

Comment: This was an interesting idea, but UserProperties are going to be stripped out of the email, at some point, and it won't be retained in the reply email I receive. So, while I can use a UserProperty to quickly find the email via Excel, I can't use it to connect a reply to the original email (sent via Excel).